# ArcSDESQLExecute seems does not work with startTransaction and commitTransaction

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I'm doing some calcultations by ArcSDESQLExecute. The idea is to make some part localy and at the end copy  table/featureclass to SDE and make some extra operations by sql. I want to put all sql to transaction,but  it seems like it does not work as a transaction.
Here is example of code, which works wrong.

```
sde_connector = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute("path to connector")
sql = [ u"ALTER TABLE {tab_mc} ADD bez_UR number(38,8)".format(tab_mc = mc_results),
        u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set test_col = 1000",
        # u"DROP TABLE TP_MC_STAT",     ##WHEN TABLE IS NOT DELETED, NEXT SQL RAISE AN EXCEPTION
        u"CREATE TABLE TP_MC_STAT (test_col int)",
        u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set test_col = 4"]
sde_connector.startTransaction()
for row in sql:
    try:
        sde_connector.execute(row)
    except Exception as err:
        raise Exception(row," ...>>>... ",err.message)
sde_connector.commitTransaction()
```

When I run full code without commenting "DROP TABLE" everything is ok and column test_col has value 4. But When I  comment  DROP statement I except no sql is gonna be commited  and test_col has still value 4. But after raising exception there is 1000 in test_col - previous sql were commited. How is this possible?

Comment: Imho, you are misusing `arcsdesqlexecute`. Just get a proper package for working with SQL Server, `pymssql`, and submit your call in one shot. No need to use the `for` loop for iteration!

Comment: There is only one reason  why I'm using arcpy tool - package management at side of my colleagues. I'm not able to  to manage their packages, but everybody has arcpy... So I'm not sure if this solution works for us.

Comment: I hear you. I don't get the results committed if an exception is raised, I've tested running your code in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5. Can you please try running just these three rows (leave all other code as is): `u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set test_col = 4", u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set test_col = ( 10 / 0)"`. No rows should be updated to value `4`.

Comment: That is strange. When I use only yours sql it works clearly, no problem it absolutely respect transaction. I started to celebrate, but when I add alter table statement like this`[ u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set z = 4",u"alter table tp_mc_stat add test number(38,8)", u"UPDATE TP_MC_STAT set z = ( 10/0)"]`, then no transaction is respected. Exception is raised, but 1st and 2nd sql is commited.

Comment: My mistake  DDL  are not transactional in ORACLE ... found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711447/oracle-ddl-and-transaction-rollback). Thanks for help

Comment: Oh, OK. I was using SQL Server for testing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a note in this [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm) stating:

> A commit may also occur when the connection to ArcSDE it terminated
>   (check specific DBMS documentation to see how each DBMS deals with a
>   disconnect while in a transaction).

If the exception causes the connection to terminate, your DBMS may commit the transaction. Try calling `rollbackTransaction()` in the catch block.

Comment: I put it there but the result is the same.